# Total guess count not updating

Tags: python

I am a beginner to coding, I am learning python and decided to make a random number guessing game. Everything went great but I want to add a guess counter and I'm not sure why the total wont update.

```
def random_num():
    guess = int(input("Guess the number, it is between 1-100: "))
    total = 0
    if guess > random_number:
        print("\nLower")
        total += 1
        random_num()
    elif guess < random_number:
        print("\nHigher")
        total += 1
        random_num()
    elif guess == random_number:
        print("\nYou win")
        print("You took " + str(total) + " guesses to get the correct number.")
```

The output is 0 for total but that is incorrect.

Comment: Do you run this in a loop? How does the user make multiple guesses?

Comment: declare `total=0` before the function. Right now, it gets reset to 0 each time the function is called.

Comment: `total` starts at `0` on every call of that function, so you'd need to make it a parameter instead. Note that `total` *does* update, you just never print it out.

Comment: Please show enough code for someone to reproduce the problem so that they might help you. Specifically, show how you're calling this function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your current code isn't called at all.  If it were, it would allow the player one guess and then exit.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem is that you reset `total` to 0 before every guess -- and then you print it only when that guess is correct, so it's always 0.

Comment: Also, please remember to do your research *before* posting.  There are many such number-guessing games already debugged on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are always declaring total to equal 0 every time you call random_num.

You need to find a way to save the value of total.

HINT: use it as a global variable. A better solution, pass total as a value, as an argument to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


num = random.randint(1, 12)

user = int(input('Please enter a number from 1 to 100:  '))

counter = 1
while user != num:
    if user > num:
        print('Too high!')
        counter += 1
    else:
        print('Too low!')
        counter += 1
    user = int(input('Please try again:  '))

print('You got it! The number is ' + str(num) + ' and it took you ' + str(counter) + ' tries.')
```

This is a simplistic approach to what you want. Notice how the counter works in the while loop and the if-else statement. We already know that the user will take at least one guess, so `counter = 1`. Every time the user is wrong, which only occurs in the if-else statement, we use `counter += 1`. Using a While statement ensures that we only add to the counter if the User is wrong.